Image of a hyperplane under finite map
If we consider the following map $f: \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ which takes $(x_0, x_1,..., x_n) \to (x_0^m, x_1^m, ..., x_n^m)$, then the image of the hyperplanes $H_i:= \{x_i= 0\}$ are also a hyperplane $H_i^{'}:=\{y_i=0\}
$. On the other hand, if $H$ be an arbitrary hyperplane and $H^{'}$ be its image, then we have $f_*H= m^{n-1}H^{'}$ and $f_*H_i= m^{n-1}H_i^{'}$. Since $H$ nad $H_i$ are linearly equivalent, $f_*H$ and $f_*H_i$ are rationally equivalent (hope they are also linearly equivalent). Thus $f(H)$ is also a hyperplane.
Please correct me if I am making any mistake.
If that is correct, then does it hold for general finite map ? More precisely,
if $f: \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ is a finite  map and $H$ is a hyperplane, then does
$f(H)$ is also a hyper plane ?

I'm confused. The image of the hyperplane $x_0+\dots+x_n=0$ under your map doesn't seem to be a hyperplane.

Probably I am missing something. I guess $f_*H$ need not be $m^{n-1}H^{'}$.

If $f \colon X \to Y$ is a finite map and $Z \subseteq X$ a closed subscheme with image $W$, then $f_[Z]$ is indeed a multiple of $[W]$, but the coefficient is the degree of the map $Z \to W$, more or less by definition of $f_$. In the case of $H_i$, the degree of $H_i \to H_i'$ is equal to $\deg f$, but for a sufficiently general hyperplane $H$, the map $H \to H'$ has degree $1$. Thus $[H'] = f_[H] \sim f_[H_i] = \deg f\ [H_i']$, from which you conclude that $H'$ is a hypersurface of degree $\deg f$.

P.S. Isn't "linearly equivalent" a synonym for "rationally equivalent" in the case of hypersurfaces?

@R.van Dobben de Bruyn     Yes. I got it. Thank you very much for pointing out the mistake.
